# using pathos with ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, concurrent.futures, pathos

its possible to use concurrent.futures (ProcessPoolExecutor) with pathos ?

asking this because when i try to use:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
```

... executor.map()

i will get:

> PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup
>   **builtin**.function failed

i know we could use pathos.multiprocess to use instead of the default multiprocess, and solve some issues like this one, the problem is when i try to implement parallel processing with futures, im not able to set a solution to fix the pickle error with pathos.

any idea ?

thanks.

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  Support for `concurrent.futures` is an open ticket: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/90.  If you mean something different, please let me know.  It's hard to tell from your question above what exactly you mean (or are trying to do).